# How to sum duplicate row values in query

Tags: c#, sql

There's my sql data:

```
ProductID   id     SQFeet Stock
---------------
3           1      2400   10
17          2      1500   20
6           3      1000   15 
17          4      3000   5
6           4      2000   34
```

But code and name has duplicated values and I want to sum total from each duplicated field. Something like this:

```
ProductID id       SQFeet Stock
---------------
3         id       2400   10
17        id       4500   25
6         id       3000   49
```

I've tried:

```
select ProductID, id, SUM(SQFeet) as SQ, SUM(Stock) as Stock from tbl_FactoryStock 
GROUP BY ProductID, id
```

But its not working for multiple group by coumns, If I use only one group by column it works fine. Like this:

```
//This works fine
select ProductID, SUM(SQFeet) as SQ, SUM(Stock) as Stock from tbl_FactoryStock 
GROUP BY ProductID
```

But when I use it for multiple group by columns, it dose not works.

How to achieve the goal for multiple group by for multiple columns?

Comment: For each record, the id is different so it is not working properly with the group by id. Why you want the id column in your result? Why you have not included that column in the input and the expected result you want?

Comment: So how can I achieve the specified result? can you alter this query to get specific result?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "not working"? Ideally provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @stuartd When id for each record is like the identity key then including in the group by column will not produce the result with the grouping one. This is the mean what I said not working.

Comment: not working means it just shows the data like: code name total
---------------
3   Sprite 2400
17  Coke   1500
6   Dew    1000
17  Coke   3000
6   Dew    2000

Comment: @SurajKumar thanks but I was asking the person who wrote the question!

Comment: @NomiTech Yes, it will give the result as it is in the input.

Comment: Suraj Kumar Brother I want id column because I need to do further quries against that id in the application. that is important.

Comment: Your sample data has `code name total` but your sample query has `ProductID, id, SQFeet, Stock` - this makes it confusing

Comment: code name total is just for example brother. You can rename them by ProductID, id, SQFeet, Stock. I am going to rename it in the question as well.

Comment: @NomiTech Whether id 4 twice is correct in the input data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Select code, name, sum(total) as total
from yourtable
group by code, name
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b6b25a266e09c7a457ab21d54841bd06) demo.

If you want to check the record id with duplicate value then you can use the below query using the windowed function.

```
Select id,
 code,
 name,
 Count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY code, name) AS TotCount,
 SUM(total) OVER(PARTITION BY code, name) AS Total
from yourtable
```

[image]

Here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=121156c4638997d19bd68cd77cef8d28) demo.

Comment: I am already trying this but as @SurajKumar said in the comment that For each record, the id is different so it is not working properly with the group by id. therefore the specified result is not coming out.

Comment: @NomiTech I have included additional query to check the total count and the id please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
CODE INT ,
NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
TOTAL INT)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3,'SPRITE',2400)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(17,'COKE',1500)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(6 ,'DEW ',1000)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(17,'COKE',3000)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(6 ,'DEW ',2000)

SELECT CODE,NAME,SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL 
FROM @T
GROUP BY CODE,NAME
```

This Query works fine for your Case:
  [image]